# c program doesn't give me errors

Tags: c, pointers, undefined-behavior, local-variables

Consider the following program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef struct my_string{
    int len;
    char *buf;
} my_string_t;


my_string_t *init_my_string(char *);
my_string_t *call_init_my_string();

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     my_string_t *st1 = call_init_my_string();

     printf("%d\n", st1->len);
     printf("%s\n", st1->buf);

     free(st1);

    return 0;
}


my_string_t *call_init_my_string()
{
    my_string_t *st1 = init_my_string("Foo");
    return st1;
}


my_string_t *init_my_string(char *s)
{
    my_string_t *st = (my_string_t *) malloc(sizeof(*st));
    st->len = strlen(s);
    st->buf = s;
    return st;
}
```

The question is,
does this program suppose to result in undefined behaviour or some kind of error? 
since the string `"Foo"` inside function `call_init_my_string` is locally declared
and get passed to `init_my_string` function. In `init_my_string` function, I allocate 
a space to hold the size of of the string and the string itself, but as i know, this 
allocation 
`my_string_t *st = (my_string_t *) malloc(sizeof(*st));` only allocate enough space for `st->len`
and `st->buf` pointer and not for string `"Foo"` since I only assign the string 
to `st->buf` instead of allocating it first and then do like the following:

```
 st->buf = (char *) malloc(strlen(s) + 1);
 memcpy(st->buf, s, strlen(s));
 st->buf[strlen(s)] ='\0';
```

But after I compile it and run, it gives me no errors and the program runs fine.
why this program works fine and gives me no errors?

this is the result printed on the screen:

```
$ gcc struct_ptr_string1.c -o struct_ptr_string1
$ ./struct_ptr_string1

3
Foo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no undefined behaviour in your code.

The string literal `"Foo"` has *static storage duration*. You are passing its address to `init_my_string` and simply store that address (essentially a pointer to `"Foo"`).

Your code is equivalent to (except we have one more copy of `"Foo"`):

```
my_string_t *call_init_my_string()
{
    static char s[] = "Foo";
    my_string_t *st1 = init_my_string(&s[0]);
    return st1;
}

my_string_t *init_my_string(char *s)
{
    my_string_t *st = malloc(sizeof(*st));
    st->len = strlen(s);
    st->buf = s;
    return st;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The "Foo" string is a constant string probably stored somewhere statically. What happens in `init_my_string` is that you indeed allocate a new memory chunk, but you will assing `st->buf` to `s` which is the pointer which points to this "Foo" string. So you dont copy "Foo", but rather just set `st->buf` to the location where it is stored.

```
my_string_t *init_my_string(char *s)
{
    my_string_t *st = (my_string_t *) malloc(sizeof(*st));
    printf("st address=%d\n", st);
    printf("s address=%d\n", s);
    st->len = strlen(s);
    st->buf = s;
    printf("st->buf address=%d\n", st->buf);
    return st;
}
```

Output:

```
st address=19779600                                                                                                                                                                
s address=4196344                                                                                                                                                                  
st->buf address=4196344                                                                                                                                                            
3                                                                                                                                                                                  
Foo
```

As you see `st->buf` actually points to the constant string thats why no error.

Comment: thank you for all of your answers, now i understand
I wish I could vote you both.